# StreamWrite WriteLine doesn't work as delegate

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, streamwriter

I would like to create a simple logger and for do that i use delegate in this way:

```
delegate void Logger(string message);
```

But when I try to create a Logger using the method below, this doesn't append anything to the file.

```
Logger CreateFileLogger(string filePath) {
            if (!File.Exists(filePath)) File.Create(filePath);
            StreamWriter stream = File.AppendText(filePath);
            return stream.WriteLine;
        }
```

I can not say with confidence whether it is a problem of the StreamWriter class or about the delegates, in any case I think the first.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're never disposing of the stream, and the stream is never flushed (because you haven't written enough) so nothing is ever written to the file.  You shouldn't be leaking disposable resources like this.

Fortunately there's no need to deal with streams at all.  Just use `File.AppendAllText` instead of creating a stream and managing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it *is* writing to the `StreamWriter` - but you're never going to close that `StreamWriter`, so it won't be flushed, and you'll leave the file handle open too - not good.

If you make sure you *do* flush and close the file, it's fine:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("test.txt"))
        {
            Action<string> logger = writer.WriteLine;
            ExecuteDelegate(logger);
        }
    }

    static void ExecuteDelegate(Action<string> logger)
    {
         logger("First line");
         logger("Second line");
         logger("Third line");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap the WriteLine in another action like:

```
Logger CreateFileLogger(string filePath) {
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) File.Create(filePath);
        StreamWriter stream = File.AppendText(filePath);
        return (str) => { stream.WriteLine(str); stream.Flush(); };
}
```

But the stream in never closed, as above answers state. Hope it helps.